# Concurrency In Practice Circular Buffer Error?

Tags: java, concurrency, circular-buffer

Finally reading through the excellent *Concurrency In Practice* book and I am came across listing 14.2 for *BaseBoundedBuffer*. As is, the put and take methods will allow for count to exceed the buffer capacity or go below 0. I get that the class is abstract but it seems strange this is the default behaviour. Is there some good reason why there would not be some logic to not allow count to go beyond capacity or below 0? Maybe something like,

```
if(count != buf.length)
     ++count;
```

```
@ThreadSafe
public abstract class BaseBoundedBuffer<V> {
     @GuardedBy("this") private final V[] buf;
     @GuardedBy("this") private final int tail;
     @GuardedBy("this") private final int head;
     @GuardedBy("this") private final int count;

     protected BaseBoundedBuffer (int capacity) {
          this.buf = (V[]) new Object[capacity];
     }

     protected synchronized final void doPut(V v) {
          buf[tail] = v;
          if (++tail == buf.length)
               tail = 0;
          ++count;
     }

      protected synchronized final V doTake() {
          V v = buf[head];
          buf[head] = null;
          if (++head == buf.length)
               head = 0;
          --count;
          return v;
     }

     public synchronized final boolean isFull() {
          return count == buf.length;
     }

     public synchronized final boolean isEmpty() {
          return count == 0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems given the example child class in the book that it was intended for the child class to have the responsibility of checking `isFull` before putting and `isEmpty` before taking. With such an implementation, checking again is a waste of time.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class GrumpyBoundedBuffer<V> extends BaseBoundedBuffer<V> {
    public GrumpyBoundedBuffer(int size) { super(size); }

    public synchronized void put(V v) throws BufferFullException {
        if (isFull())
            throw new BufferFullException();
        doPut(v);
    }

    public synchronized V take() throws BufferEmptyException {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new BufferEmptyException();
        return doTake();
    }
}
```

In the real world, an appropriate JavaDoc explaining how these methods are intended to be used would be crucial to avoiding the two potential bugs you have identified.

It should go without saying that just because something is in a book doesn't mean it is correct, optimal, or even good. You were right to be skeptical about the implementation.

Comment: Totally understand that this is not a copy and paste code but was more surprised there wasn't some sort of documentation indicating a lurking bug and that there was a large assumption left to the implementer, particularly given past chapters on the need for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

We should never let `count` run out of bounds, but this example supposes that checking this condition is propagated to the caller. We can't just throw an exception, because in a multithreaded program such behavior may be expected and handled in a non-exceptional way (e.g. just waiting for the condition to fulfill). We can't just say `if(count != buf.length) ++count;` either, because this would be a part of handling logic and could clash with the logic implemented in the caller or subclass.

This example is a part of a bigger picture - the chapter `14.1.1. Example: propagating precondition failure to callers` describes an approach where the exceptional case is handled by the subclass. The chapter describes two "painful" ways to implement such functionality (throwing an exception or `sleep`ing the thread) and then provides a more robust approach - using condition queues (see chapter 14.1.3).

I'd like to stress that the code example you've mentioned is not an implementation to copy-and-paste, it's just means of getting to the point.

Comment: Of course I understand this isn't drop in code to be used and given the point of the chapter the author is trying to stress something else but was surprised more from a teaching perspective that there would be a large, undocumented assumption that one must implement the class in a certain way to make it work correctly.

Comment: I think the base class itself is there just not to repeat code in different examples. It's not supposed to be copied or extended anywhere outside of the example code in this chapter - so the explanations in the text of the chapter seem a sufficient documentation to me.